# Java - Process an event after #ms without blocking the thread

Tags: java

Currently I'm attempting to add some spacing in-between two called methods sent to the client. This can be done by issueing a `Thread.sleep()` command however I don't want to stop all of my logic that's going on in that thread. Instead I'm looking for a more `asynchronous` approach.

For example: lets say I have the following code.

```
void() {
   foo();
   then();
   bar();
}
```

and I want them to execute in a spaced interval without effecting the main thread, like this

```
void() {
    foo(); 
    wait 500ms -> then();
    wait 500ms -> bar();
}
```

I've looked into executors, but it seems they all execute on a seperate thread, then I looked into some of guavas executors, but none of them seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

You can time the execution by using a `ScheduledExecutorService` and its `schedule()` method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html .

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService =
        Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduledExecutorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code
    }
}, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, just saw you dont want to use Executors. :(